# How to mask rails controller completely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I have a very simple question to ask. How do I mask the controller in my url? I want this so that I can show a clean domain whether the user is logged in or not (different controller).

My routes.rb

```
  root :to => "users#index"
  get 'home', to: 'home#index'
```

My Users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController    
  def index
    #@users = User.all
    if session[:user_id]
      ...
    else
      redirect_to '/home'
    end
  end
end
```

Currently, if the user is logged in, the root_path is http://www.mydomain.com (that's good!).

But, if the user is not logged in, the root_path is http://www.mydomain.com/home. I want the '/home' removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have one unique url at a time.

```
def index
  if session[:user_id]
    ...
  else
    #redirect_to '/home'
    render 'a_page' #this will ensure separate page with same url
  end
end
```

Comment: i prefer this solution than messing with my routes file

Answer (score 0):

You can use constraints in the routes.rb file

```
# User is logged in
constraints(lambda { |request| !request.session[:user_id].blank? }) do
    root :to => "users#index"
end

# User is not logged in
root :to => "home#index"
```